# Updating a redis client hash

Tags: node.js, hash, redis

I would like to update and add an item to the redis hash session entry.

I have been able to create a hash using the redis client using the code below:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

client.hmset('frameworks', {
    'javascript': 'AngularJS',
    'css': 'Bootstrap',
    'node': 'Express'
});
```

Is there a way of adding to this hash? I would like to change and also to update an existing hash element.

Is this possible without reading everything and creating a new hash with updated and new hash elements.

I am using this webpage as a tutorial guide : https://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/

Comment: I was think if i wanted to add to this hash I could just call client.hmset with new data and it would add to the existing session hash? But what about updating?

Comment: Yes you can just use hset/hmset based on one or more fields.. See the example added here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use same **hmset/hset** based on how many you want to add or update

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(); //creates a new client

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

client.hmset('frameworks', {
    'javascript': 'AngularJS',
    'css': 'Bootstrap',
    'node': 'Express'
});
```

Say you initially have this and want to add db : mongo, and want to update node: Express4 then you can just use

```
//If you know will update only one use hset instead
client.hmset('frameworks', {
    'node': 'Express4',
    'db' : 'MongoDB'
});
```

Will add db & update node too for the key frameworks

Comment: I will try this out and leave feedback tomorrow. Many Thanks Jerry and @Dario

Comment: how would I get out an individual element from the hash table ?

Comment: You can use "hget keyName member name". EX : client.hget('frameworks', 'node', function(err, res){})

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the `key` or hash `field` already exists in the hash, they are overwritten.

So, to add or update one field you can use [`hset`](http://redis.io/commands/HSET), or [`hmset`](http://redis.io/commands/HMSET) if you want to insert/upsert multiple fields.

If you want to overwrite the entire hash with a new one discarding previous values, you can use [`client.multi()`](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clientmulticommands) and use a combination of `del` and `hmset` commands, to execute them in a transaction.